# How to move the cursor between div elements with the arrow keys

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

**How do i move the cursor between div elements** like [Notion](https://www.notion.so)'s editor?

```html
<div>
    hello
    word
</div>
<div>hi</div>
<div>notion</div>
```

with the code as above, how to move the cursor to another div element when the cursor is moved with the arrow keys?

for example, suppose the current cursor is in front of "hello".

1. when the arrow key is pressed down, the cursor moves forward to "word".
2. if you press the down arrow key once more, the cursor moves to "hi", the content of the next div element.

Answer (score 2):

You can't move the actual mouse cursor. That would lead to serious issues, as the website could just trick you into clicking on some specific elements you didn't want to click on. 
It is still possible to change the focus to an element with Javascript or you can just highlight the selected element by adding and removing CSS-classes.  
For Example:

```
.box:hover{
background: blue; /* make this whatever you want */
}
```

Comment: oh i made a mistake... It's not a mouse cursor, it's a keyboard cursor